# HighCharts Semi-Circle-Donut, remove margin and padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I've been trying to remove the margin and the padding from an HighCharts **semi-circle-donut**.

I've tried both with `margin: [0,0,0,0]` and all the different four spacing properties. I've also tried to set the `size` property of plotOptions to 100%.

I've created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W7bXw/1/ to demonstrate the issue and the options I've tried. As you can see there're still huge paddings between the semi-circle and the container.

The funny thing is that setting either margin or spacing to 0 works on regular pies from HighCharts.

**UPDATE**:

According to the accepted answer the solution for this chart is to use negative margin together with an explicit height for the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should help you: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.margin
Here you can find how you can make the padding of your chart smaller, or 0.
Add this your chart script and change the values as you need them to fit in your page

```
chart: {
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 100,
            marginLeft: 100,
            marginRight: 100
}
```

***UPDATE:***
Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/W7bXw/2/

You have to set a width to your div #container and just then set the margins.

Comment: As already stated in the question, and showed in the jsfiddle it doesn't work for semi-circle-donut. Try to edit the fiddle and update it if you get it working.

Comment: I saw you're using negative margins, and that's almost OK. I'll work on it to get exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following options work for me

In the chart options, move the chart up by negative top and bottom margin.

```
chart: {
   marginTop: -50,
   marginBottom: -50,
   marginLeft: 0,
   marginRight: 0,
}
```

Inside the plot options size should be `size: '100%'`.

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
       dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,                    
            style: {
               fontWeight: 'bold',
               color: 'black',
           }
        },
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '75%']
    }
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is something you expect

```
 series: [{
        pointPadding: 0,
         groupPadding: 0,
        type: 'pie',
        size: '100%',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '150%',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            ['Chrome', 12.8],
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
```

change the innerSize to 150% and try